# How can I find dead code in multiple solutions?(c#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, dead-code

The source consists of more than 10 solutions.
One of these solutions has dozens of public methods that the other solutions can refer to. How can I find dead codes that are not referenced in each solution among the public methods? I heard that Resharper is useful for finding dead codes. is it possible to find dead codes for multiple solutions?

Answer (score 0):

If you add all solutions' projects to single solution, there will be only one solution. In that case, possible solutions for your problem is explained in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30974433/get-list-of-zero-reference-codes-in-visual-studio).

For my personal view, the best method is using CodeLens but it may not be enough for your all need.

The other alternative is writing your own application by using Roslyn parser. Basically all you have to do is give your source code to Roslyn and find the referenced methods which is explained in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46032472/find-all-references-in-visual-studio-solution-using-roslyn) as well.

Comment: @daish: Note that a single project may be part of multiple solutions at the same time.  You can leave your multiple solutions alone and create a new empty solution.  Add each of the projects (from all of the existing solutions) into this new project and do your work from that new solution.